# ActiveRecord scope based on a child scope condition and include those children with that condition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How do you write a scope returns itself based on the condition of the child AND includes those children ONLY in that condition.

For instance, how can I write a scope that returns all `Organizations` that have published jobs, AND include those published jobs (while excluding the non published ones).

Would this require two queries?

```
# Organization.rb
scope :with_published_jobs, lambda {
  joins(:jobs)
    .merge(Job.published)
    .includes(:jobs).where(published: true)
    # doesnt work
}
```

Org model

```
class Org < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :jobs, autosave: true
  ...
```

Job model..

```
class Job < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :orgs
```

the two models are relation with a join table

Comment: Can you add the models and/or migrations to see how are they related?

Comment: I've updated my question @SebastianPalma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to create a different association on your Organization model and use that instead of `jobs`.

```rb
# Organization
has_and_belongs_to_many :published_jobs, -> { where(published: true) }, class_name: 'Job'
scope :with_published_jobs, -> { joins(:published_jobs).includes(:published_jobs) }
```